# Decay chain browser

Tags: graphs-and-networks, physics, education

This https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IsotopeBrowser/ used to be an excellent tool to demonstrate decay chains to my students. Unfortunately it does not work under newer versions of mma. Can anybody fix the bug? Thx in advance!

Comment: It may be useful to show what error you're encountering, and include what version you are using and what version it last worked on